# Why can't a class static constexpr value depend on a class static constexpr function?

Tags: c++, constexpr

Anyone know if there is something wrong with the following or if it is a bug?

```c++
#include <utility>

struct X {
    template <typename...Ts>
    static constexpr std::size_t fn() {
        return 1;
    }
    static constexpr std::size_t value = fn();
};
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/DXl2B-)</kbd>

Looks like msvc 19.22 seems to be ok with it, but clang and gcc don't like it.

If I move the fn() template external to the struct, it works fine.
clang says:

```
error: constexpr variable 'value' must be initialized by a constant expression
```

and gcc says:

```
static constexpr std::size_t X::fn() [with Ts = {}; std::size_t = long unsigned int]' used before its definition
```

Also, can't define later:

```c++
struct X {
    template <typename...Ts>
    static constexpr std::size_t fn() {
        return 1;
    }
    static constexpr std::size_t value;
};
constexpr std::size_t X::value = X::fn();
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/yd_0bx)</kbd>

However, it can be specified as a constexpr function:

```c++
struct X {
    template <typename...Ts>
    static constexpr std::size_t fn() {
        return 1;
    }
    static constexpr std::size_t value() {
        return fn();
    }
};
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/-OIB6o)</kbd>

This appears to be caused by the class not being complete at use.  If so, it would seem to be a deficiency since static member vars/fns don't depend on the class.

### EDIT

Thanks @Rakete1111.  Looking at the duplicate you provided, I got this quote from the standard (emphasis mine):

> 9.4.2 [class.static.data] p3: ... A static data member of literal type ***can*** be declared in the class definition with the constexpr specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression.

As **can** is not the same as **must**, this further indicates a deficiency as my second example should have then worked.

Comment: You say: "static constexpr std::size_t X::count_params(Ts ...) [with Ts = {int, int, int, int};..." but I don't see in your code any definition of X::count_params. Please provide full code.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov, sorry, pasted wrong error msg.  Fixed.